# checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled deprecated for ios 9

Tags: objective-c, google-signin

according to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in.html#method-detail)  checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled is deprecated, looking over the documentation I couldn't find an equivalent or alternative for ios9 that doesn't force me to display a webView for single sign on, 
Does anyone knows something on how to do this?